# Unsupported operand types (View: C:\Users\10User\fyp2.2\resources\views\route\editRoute.blade.php)

Tags: laravel

Routes

```
Route::get('/editRoute/{id?}',['uses'=>'RouteController@edit' , 'as' =>'route.editRoute']);
```

Edit View blade

```
{!! Form::select('driver_id', ['$driver_id' => '---Select Driver---']+$drivers, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Edit Controller

```
$routes = Route::find($id);
return view('route.editRoute', compact('routes'));
```

Comment: Can anyone help me on this case where I had to retrieve a drop down data from database but I couldn't be able to perform that function?

Comment: how are you getting the drivers?

Comment: $drivers = $drivers->get()->pluck('name', 'id');

Comment: and if you dd $drivers is it null? if so you are concatenating null and array, hence the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change that in one of two ways:

- Add placeholder:

  `{!! Form::select('driver_id', $drivers, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'---Select Driver---']) !!}`
- Change current select list:

  `{!! Form::select('driver_id', ['' => '---Select Driver---']+$drivers, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}`

Both option will work but first is my preferred :)